# Passing VC data not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

When a user taps on an image in my application, I would like for that to send them to another view controller to give them more post details but I can't quite figure out how to transfer that image from one view controller to the next!

The code below, should they tap the image, should send them to the detailed view controller - this is done so in the else if statement.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       if username != PFUser.currentUser()?.username {
            let profileVC: UserProfileViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UserProfileViewController
            profileVC.usernameString = username

       } else if (segue.identifier == "toPostDetail") {
            var svc = segue.destinationViewController as! PostDetailsViewController

            svc.toPass = // Call/pass the image
      }
 }
```

To retrieve all the posts in my database I use the following code, this runs perfectly fine but I need to get the postImage trasnfered to the next view controller.

```
postsArray[indexPath.row]["image"].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in
            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                postCellObj.postImage.image = downloadedImage
                postCellObj.postImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
                postCellObj.postImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

            }
        }
```

So what would I put in the svc.toPass in order for the image to be sent to the other view controller? Since this is an array of posts, would I have to do something with didSelectRowAtIndexPath or am I doing the right thing? I am also using Parse.com to get information to and from my databases.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the post rather than the image, so it would be something like

```
postsArray[indexPath.row]
```

How you get the `indexPath` is up to you. If the segue is triggered by a cell selection then you could store the `indexPath` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, or you could pass the `indexPath` as the `sender` when you trigger the segue, or you could use `indexPathForSelectedRow` if it's retained during the segue process.

Comment: where are you calling postsArray[indexPath.row]?

Comment: `svc.toPass = postsArray[indexPath.row]` - you just need to decide where to get `indexPath` from at that point in time

Comment: In my other view controller, what should the variable toPass be set to?

Comment: A PFObject (or subclass of) so you have direct access to all the details

Comment: Is there a way I can contact you outside SO like skype or something quick? Having some issues - dont want to flood this post with comments

Comment: Just add comments, eventually you'll be high enough to join a chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102410/discussion-between-wain-and-griffin-morandini).